# angularjs - Error: ui-jq: The "tooltip" function does not exist

Tags: javascript, angularjs, grails

I am using **angularjs/[angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/)** with **groovy&grails**.

### I have following configuration

**1) My `ApplicationResources.groovy` is**

```
    angularJs { 
       resource url:'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.min.js' 
    }

    angularUI {
        dependsOn 'angularJs'
        dependsOn 'jQuery'
        resource url:'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.min.css',attrs:[rel: "stylesheet", type:'css']
        resource url:'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.min.js'
        resource url:'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui-ieshiv.min.js'
      }

    angularStrap {
        dependsOn 'angularJs'
        dependsOn 'bootstrapJs'
        dependsOn 'datepicker'
        resource url: 'js/angular-strap/angular-strap.min.js'
        resource url: 'js/angular-strap/timepicker.js'
      }

      angularUserApp {
        dependsOn 'angularResources'
        dependsOn 'angularUI'
        dependsOn 'angularStrap'
        resource url:'js/angular-app/user/app.js'

        resource url:'js/angular-app/user/controller/KnowledgeController.js'
        resource url:'js/angular-app/user/service/KnowledgeService.js'
      }

      userJs { resource url:'js/user.js' }
```

**2) ngular-app module(user/app.js) is**

```
var user = angular.module('user', [ 'ui', '$strap.directives' ]);
user.value('ui.config', {
  jq : {
    tooltip : {
      placement : 'bottom'
    }
  }
});
```

**3) `user/controller/KnowledgeController.js`**

```
KnowledgeController.$inject = [ '$scope', '$http', 'knowledgeService'];
```

**4) layout `user.gsp` with `ng-app` is**

```
<html ng-app="user" lang="en">
<!-- other code goes here -->
</html>
```

**5) `knowledge.gsp` with `ng-controller` is**

```
   <html>
            <head>
                    <meta name="layout" content="user">
            </head>
    <body>
    <div id="controller" class="container-fluid" ng-controller="KnowledgeController">
    <g:form id="uploadKnowledge" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset class="gray">
            <div>
              <label for="name">Knowledge Name </label>
              <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="knowledge.name" ui-jq="tooltip" title="Knowledge name" required/>
            </div>
    </div>
 <r:require modules="angularUserApp" />
 <r:require modules="bootstrapJs" />
 <r:require modules="userJs" />
 <r:require modules="angularJs" /> 
 <r:require modules="angularStrap" />
    </body>
    </html>
```

**When knowledge.gsp is rendered, I get following error**

```
Error: ui-jq: The "tooltip" function does not exist
    at Object.compile (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.min.js:7:5102)
    at ja (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.min.js:49:236)
    at V (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.min.js:41:488)
    at V (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.min.js:42:70)
    at V (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.min.js:42:70)
    at V (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.min.js:42:70)
    at V (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.min.js:42:70)
    at V (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.min.js:42:70)
    at V (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.min.js:42:70)
    at V (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.min.js:42:70)
```

I can see angular-ui `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.min.js` properly loaded(Screenshot is available below).

[image: Angular-UI]

Comment: Have you injected `ui` provider to the app module? How does the angular app look like? It should look like `angular.module("user". ['ui'])`

Comment: Yes, I have app module defined(in `js/angular-app/user/app.js`) as `var user = angular.module('user', [ 'ui', '$strap.directives' ]);`